# Check if document field has value firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to check if certain field in a collection has a value.

I have a collection of users and that collection has a documents by their uid than that document has a field bio.

I want to check if that field is empty or not.

This is where i'm at at the moment...

```
  const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(auth.user.uid).get()
  docRef.then((querySnapshot) => {
    if(querySnapshot.docs[0].data() != ''){
      //there is value in field
    }
  })
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i get en error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`  like the docs is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `db.collection('users').doc(auth.user.uid).get()` you define a Promise that resolves with a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) (and **not** a `QuerySnapshot`). A `DocumentSnapshot` does not have any `docs` property.

So you need to do as follows:

```
const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(auth.user.uid).get();
docRef.then((docSnapshot) => {
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        if (docSnapshot.data().bio === '') {
           // Bio is empty
        }
    } else {
        // docSnapshot.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

---

Note that from a naming convention perspective, it would make more sense to write:

```
const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(auth.user.uid); // This is a DocumentReference
docRef.get().then((doc) => {...});
```